# Ruby File Monitor of an NFS mount (Can't use iNotify)

Tags: ruby, inotify, file-monitoring

I need to find another way to monitor a directory recursively on an NFS mount on linux box.

Polling seems to be my only option. Any others? Is there a file monitor in ruby that doesn't use inotify?

Inotify requires the kernel and an nfs mount has the limitation that it cannot work over networked file system mounts.

Thanks for any ideas.

edit: This is to be used in my code, not a stand-alone command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

Ara Howard's dirwatch might be a good fit for you.  I don't believe it uses iNotify

http://codeforpeople.com/lib/ruby/dirwatch/dirwatch-0.9.0/README

Comment: guess I wasn't clear. I was looking for a gem or module to include in my code. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I didn't look very hard, but it seems to me that 'dirwatch' is just the executable, and there is actual code you can use : http://codeforpeople.com/lib/ruby/dirwatch/dirwatch-0.9.0/lib/

Comment: I looked at the source, cool module, but alas I can't use it because I don't have write permission to the directory I'm watching. I'd have to basically edit the code to put /.dirwatch/ somewhere else which is more over-head than I was looking for.